# Specify Location of Uploaded File on the Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the script provided as an answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/macro-to-attach-files-in-excel/2d00eb08-217f-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5?msgId=9a3bd409-397f-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) to upload a file to an Excel document. How can I specify where I want the icon for the file to show up? As it is, the icon automatically shows up over the button I've assigned the VBA script to.

Comment: Did you try selecting a cell where you the icon? Say row=10, col=10,         ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 10).Select
  
  ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fullFileName, Link:= _
    False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _
    iconToUse, IconIndex:=0, IconLabel:=fullFileName).Select

Comment: That worked perfectly. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cell where you need to show the icon

Say row=10, col=10

> ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 10).Select ' this will focus the required cell
>
> ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fullFileName, Link:= _ False,
>   DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconFileName:= _ iconToUse, IconIndex:=0,
>   IconLabel:=fullFileName).Select

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim fn As String, sht as Worksheet
fn = "C:\Users\fffffffff\Desktop\tester.xlsx"
Set sht = ActiveSheet
With sht.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fn, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True)
    .Left = sht.Range("E5").Left
    .Top = sht.Range("E5").Top
End With
```